# Is there any way to use a jQuery overlay to confirm/reject node deletion?

Tags: 7, nodes, forms, javascript

When I delete a node (any type of node, presumably), I'd like to have the confirmation happen through a jQuery-like yes/no dialog popping up over the page, rather than being redirected to a separate page with the "This action cannot be undone" message.  This being the 21st century and all...

http://bootboxjs.com/ would seem to be a good candidate for handling the dialogs, but the question is how to tie it into the form and node deletion processes, ideally without hacking core and/or patching everything in site.  Has anybody thought this through?

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to do that with:

https://drupal.org/project/ctools_automodal_admin

> Provides automatic modal support for any hook_menu() paths that have
>   'modal' => TRUE defined. This makes it easy to add optional modal
>   support in any contrib module and helps reduce the burden on module
>   developers to support modals.

If you added the node delete path, perhaps `node/%node/delete` to the modal paths, it may just work.

Comment: Excellent pointer; thanks! Sadly, though, the module has some problems. It started by throwing some errors that I was able to get fixed (https://drupal.org/node/1614984), and could at least get a "create a node" form coming up in a modal. But node/%/edit and node/%/delete both did something with node permissions that blocked any editing attempts. I might look into this some more, but there's also the matter that the project seems to have been inactive for more than a year, so I'm not sure what its future is. It was definitely on the right track (thanks again!), but I fear the search continues.

Comment: Regarding add/edit: it also didn't play nicely with some jQuery validation I was doing on the form, which I suppose I shouldn't be too surprised by.